# Transform Option: Affect Only ... not working?

Tags: transforms, origin

While using [Transform Options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/options.html), selecting `Origin` I can easily move an Origin by hitting `G` (for moving). But if I adjust the Values in the [Object Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html) it seems not to affect the `Origins`. Is this a bug? (Using Blender 3.31 LTS)

(This is also not working for the `Parents`-option)